# Rails on Heroku - Site does not load - ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "image.jpg" is not present in the asset pipeline.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, assets, pipeline

I've build a simple website, using Rails so I can deploy it to Heroku. It runs perfectly locally, everything works fine. It deploys fine to Heroku but when opening the webpage (http://a-clean.herokuapp.com/) I get the following error displayed:

We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

When I check the logs (running heroku logs in terminal) it shows the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "a_clean_sample_1.jpg" is not present in the asset pipeline.)
```

So far this is just a one-page website with a couple of partials. Here is the github repository: https://github.com/webbc99/a-clean

The image it's failing on is loaded in app/views/welcome/home.html.erb line 57.

Rails version 5.1.6, Ruby version 2.5.0

I've double checked that the images are in fact in the app/assets/images folder, and the image_tags are using the file extensions.

I've tried running `heroku run rake assets:precompile`, and I've tried using the `rails12factor` gem and also without it. I have tried changing `config.assets.compile = false` to `true` in the config/environments/production.rb which did get the page to load but all of the images were ignoring styling and were huge.

What is really confusing me is that I have deployed several other rails apps, same rails version, same ruby version, and none of these have had this issue before.

Here is a working app:
https://github.com/webbc99/presumptuous
https://presumptuous.herokuapp.com/

Any help would be greatly appreciated, been googling this for hours with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the simplest way to fix this problem is; You need to run as follows;

1. `rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m {message}`
4. `git push heroku master` (push the code to the heroku again)

I tried to do it from your code and work fine.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I think the issue I was having was that I was running the rake assets:precompile on heroku with heroku run. Thanks very much for the prompt solution :)